# React setState callback not showing current state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I've been dealing for a couple of hours with something thats really making my brain boil....

I have the following code inside a function :

```
this.setState({disableFixedPeriods, allowApplyFilters: false}, () => {
    console.log("APP FINISHED DISABLING FIXED PERIODS: ", this.state.allowApplyFilters)
});
```

The console shows 'APP FINISHED DISABLING FIXED PERIODS: true'

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE:**

Heres the culprit:

```
  setFilter = (newFilters, callback) => {
    let stateFilters = { ...this.state.filters };
    let filters = Object.assign(stateFilters, newFilters);
    this.setState({ filters, allowApplyFilters: true }, callback);
  };
```

Comment: Can you show more relevant code like the constructor? Maybe you're setting the state twice somewhere and it's being overwritten?

Comment: @SterlingArcher you were right. I've added the code that was overwiting allowApplyFilters. So I asume its a race condition thats happening, right?

Comment: Yeah, my answer was wrong. You just have a race condition. Is this impeding you from doing something else?